# Is this proof that $0x = 0$ correct?

Tags: abstract-algebra, field-theory, solution-verification

I was wondering if this proof I wrote for $0x = 0$ (using only the field axioms) is correct. The proof is as follows:

$$0x = (1-1)x = x-x = 0$$

Comment: I think this relies on $(-1)x=-x$. Can you prove that?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are a lot of steps you skipped. First, -1 is defined as the inverse of 1, so a rigorous notation is (-1).

$0 x = (1 + (-1))x = x + (-1)x$

The first equality is the axiom of the inverse element, the second the distributive axiom. Now you should you prove $(-1) x = -x$, by definition, you'll have to prove that $x + (-1)x = 0$. So, after that $x + (-1)x = x + (-x) = 0$. The last equality is from the axiom of the inverse element.